# How can I delete memo posted ATM transactions through jXchange?

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

On a Silverlake core, I'm trying to identify memo posted ATM deposit transactions so these memo posts can be deleted. To delete the transaction with a TrnMod request, I understand that I need the BatchNum and SeqNum of the memo post.

I can find the memo post transaction through an AcctMemoPostSrch request, but the SeqNum=1 for all memo post transactions in the search results and there is no BatchNum.  How can I get this information in order to delete this memo post through a TrnMod?

Answer (score 0):

The jackhenry.dev portal has this blurb on the [FAQ section for TrnMod](https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/trnmod/developer-resources/) about how to roll back memo-posted transactions -

Q: If our application performs a Debit via TrnAdd on an account, and we want to rollback this transaction. Do we just call the TrnMod service with the Dlt field set to true?

A: Yes, you would use TrnMod but with the following fields as a bare minimum: • AcctId • AcctType • Dlt • TrnRcptId

Please keep in mind the TrnMod only works on same day transactions before EOD occurs. After EOD the transaction is hard posted and cannot be deleted. At that point you would need to perform a TrnAdd and reverse the credits/debits that occurred on the original transaction.

EDIT - the info above assumes you're doing a TrnAdd to create the transaction, which would return the TrnRcptId in the response. Take a look at the [AcctMemoPostSrch](https://jackhenry.dev/open-enterprise-api-docs/enterprise-soap-api/api-reference/core-services/acctmemopostsrch/) operation. That one can be used to pull back TrnRcptId's for specific account IDs.

Comment: I'm not clear how to get the TrnRcptId for a given transaction since the txn wouldn't have been entered through jXchange in the first place. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Good point. I've updated the answer above, see AcctMemoPostSrch to get back TrnRcptIds.